# How to use OpenMP with RcppEigen?

Tags: c++, r, openmp, eigen, rcpp

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to use **OpenMP** to enable the **Eigen** parallelization. My C++ code has many matrix products so the **Eigen** parallelization should play a role. However, I don't observe any difference of speed.

In the **Makevars** file, I have:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

In the **cpp** file, I have, at the beginning:

```cpp
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif 

#include <RcppEigen.h>
```

And in the main C++ function, I have:

```cpp
Eigen::setNbThreads(4);
```

Comment: ah, one has to use `#pragma omp parallel`...

Comment: Are you sure? The pragma should be inside the functions. If you put it in front of a library function, you might just let every thread do the whole function instead of distributing work. I mean one can write a library such that this works, but I haven't seen that until now.

Comment: @Paul Yes, inside. As shown [here](https://tdhock.github.io/blog/2019/omp/).

Comment: I just meant that when trying to enable the parallelization of a llibrary, normally one doesn't use pragmas, because they should already be in the library. Therefore  your comment seemed dubious.